# Run time DLLs in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webforms

DLLs located in bin folder of a ASP.Net web application are compiled. However at the run time they all will be converted to a Native code by the CLR.

My Questions is, there are over 100 DLLs in the bin folder of my ASP.Net application hosted in IIS, Do all those will be converted to native code if a user request one page from that web application?

Comment: The short answer is yes - as long as code is loaded from a DLL and used,  it'll be compiled to native code. ~100 DLL-s are not that many (and code / metadata size also affects compilation time / memory use).

Comment: I understand that code(DLL) related to the page is being requested should be compiled to the native code. But the other DLLs are not required to run the requested page. For example: there are DLLs used for some calculations which will not be used by the page requested.